# Solve $x^2-7x+10 < 0$ and give the sum of the integer solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So factoring we get the equivalent inequality $$(x-5)(x-2) < 0 \\ x<5 \ \  \text{and} \ \ x<2.$$ How does one combine this fact to an expression like this: $2<x<5$?

Because, according to my results, x should be LESS than two, not greater.

Comment: So I can just choose whatever I like of the two? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: $2 <x <5$ is the right answer. if you take $x=1$, the inequality is not satisfied.

Comment: @Parseval If $\;x<2\;$ then it is **also** $\;x<5\;$ and thus $\;(x-5)(x-2)>0\;$ ...

Comment: In general, if $a < 0$ and $b < 0$ then $ab > 0.$ Try this with $a = x - 5$ and $b = x - 2$ and see how it contradicts what you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The correct solution is -
$$(x - 5)(x - 2) < 0$$
Which implies,
$$x > 2 \textrm{ and } x < 5$$

Think of it this way, let $f(x)$ be -
$$(x - 5)(x - 2)$$

**Case 1**: let $x$ be number greater than 5, for any such value of $x$ both the terms of our expression would be positive and hence the value of $f(x)$ would also be positive.

**Case 2**: let $x$ be a number less than 2, for any such $x$ both the terms of our expression would be negative and the value of $f(x)$ would be positive again (negative times negative is positive).

**Case 3**: let $x$ be a number in between 2 and 5 (exclusive). For any such $x$, one term $(x - 2)$ would be positive and the other $(x - 5)$ would be negative, hence the overall value of $f(x)$ would be negative.

Case 3 is being questioned here.

Answer (score 2):

a product is negative of one factor is negative and the other positive, thus we have two cases:
$$x<2$$ and $$x>5$$ contradiction or
$$x>2$$ and $$x<5$$ this is the given solution $$2<x<5$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's where something called sign analysis really helps. Rather than looking at this purely algebraically, look at it geometrically. We know this is a parabola, so there are three areas of interest. $(-\infty, 2)$, $(2, 5)$, and $(5, \infty)$. Note that there are only a few areas where the sign can possibly change - before and after the zeros.

Looking at the first region, we see that both the factors, $(x-5)$ and $(x-2)$ will be negative. Therefore, the function will be positive.

In the second, $(x-5) \lt 0$, but $(x-2) \gt 0$. Therefore, their product will be negative.

In the last, $(x-5)$ and $(x-2)$ will be positive. Therefore, the function will be positive.

From this, you can see that there is only one region that works - $(2, 5)$, so $2 \lt x \lt 5$

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion that $x<5$ and $x<2$ is incorrect.

You have that $(x-5)(x-2)<0$ so need two values which multiple together to be less than zero. This will only happen if one of the numbers is positive and the other is negative. There are two choices:

- $x-5>0$ and $x-2<0$

This lead to $x>5$ and $x<2$ which is impossible. So there is no solution in this case.

- $x-5<0$ and $x-2>0$

This leads to $x<5$ and $x>2$ which combines to give $2<x<5$ which is the solution from your book.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, the most beautiful, informative and educative way to work this out is with a mix of algebra and geometry: the expression $\;y=(x-5)(x-2)=x^2-7x+10\;$ is an upwards *straight* parabola which vanishes at $\;x=2,\,5\;$ . If we know what such a parabola looks like (and this is usually junior high school stuff), it is only a matter of taking a peek at a drawing, say $${}$$
[image]

$${}$$$${}$$
where, in our case, $\;b=\frac72\;,\;\;c=10\;$ and the left intersection point of the parabola with the $\;x\,-$ axis is $\;2\;$ , and the right one is $\;5\;$  . Then, it is clear the parabola is negative precisely for $\;2<x<5\;$ , and it is positive for $\;x<2\;\;\text{or}\;\;x>5\;$ .

In fact, the official mathematics program in high school here in Israel uses (or at least *used*) the above method to solve this kind of inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a table.

$$\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|}\text{Term}&[-\infty,2]&2&[2,5]&5&[5,\infty]\\\hline(x-2)&-&0&+&+&+\\(x-5)&-&-&-&0&+\\\text{Product}
\end{array}\right]$$

Maybe you can finish the table.